# Swift - PrepareForSegue fails to pass sender.tag (nil value in other ViewController Label)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8, segue

I try to create a bulk of button programmatically then when I click on each button, it will show me the value of the button tag in another ViewController Label.

My code to create button:

```
for index in 0..<ID.count {
        let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
        button.tag = ID[index]
        button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)}
```

My button action function:

```
func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!)
{
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueIdentifier", sender: self)
}
```

My prepareForSegue function:

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "segueIdentifier") {
        var svc = segue.destinationViewController as NextViewController;

        var tag = sender.tag
        svc.toPass = "\(tag)"
    }
}
```

My Code in NextViewController:

```
    var toPass: String!

@IBOutlet var testLabel: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    testLabel.text = toPass
}
```

I have already linked both ViewController by push segue. However, when I click on the button, the label in NextViewController shows "nil". 
If I change  **svc.toPass = "(tag)"** to **svc.toPass = "something"**, the label will shows "something". Maybe there are some problems with the sender in prepareForSegue function. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah it's about the sender parameter. In the button touch handler:

```
func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!)
{
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueIdentifier", sender: self)
}
```

you're performing the segue, passing `self` as sender, i.e. the view controller instance. In `prepareForSegue` you're reading the sender's tag property, which is the view controller's tag.

I think you can fix that by just passing the button instance as sender:

```
func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!)
{
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueIdentifier", sender: sender)
    //                                                         ^^^^^^
}
```